# Regex.Match goups includes full string, how to exclude

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following code;

```
var pattern = "(\".*\") (\".*\")";
var regex = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
```

The value for input would be similar to this;

"string part1" "string part2"

The regex groups include the following

```
groups[0] = "string part1" "string part2"
groups[1] = "string part1"
groups[2] = "string part2"
```

Is there a way to exclude groups[0] as I simply want to concatenate the strings while removing the " " between them so that it becomes;

> "string part1string part2"

Comment: Why do you access Group 0 then? Just grab Group 1 and 2 values.

Comment: I was hoping to simply exclude it from the groups so I can iterate through them and concatenate without having to say exclude the first. The number of groups is dynamic, could be 2, could be 20.

Comment: So, you may just use LINQ `Skip(1)`. Then concat the rest. Show the code.

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/zmE3Nj

Comment: Yes, I thought similar myself. Thanks, that is close to what I need and I can figure the rest out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use LINQ `.Skip(1)` on the values you have in groups. Then, concat the rest of the items:

```
var input = "\"string part1\" \"string part2\"";
var pattern = "\"(.*)\" \"(.*)\"";
var match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
if (match.Success) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("\"{0}\"",
        string.Join(
            " ",
            match.Groups
              .Cast<Group>()
              .Select(x=>x.Value)
              .Skip(1)
        )
    );
}
```

See the [C# demo online](https://ideone.com/zmE3Nj).

Note I also moved the capturing group bounds inside the quotes to get rid of the quotation marks in the group values.

Also, consider an alternative pattern in case you want to match substrings between the closest quotes: `var pattern = "\"([^\"]*)\" \"([^\"]*)\"";`.